# Dynamic table with HTML and jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I need to write a Javascript UI web page for booking appointments in a hair saloon. It will have a dynamic table with the saloon opening hours on one horizontal axis and the stylists on the vertical. The page will a also have a list of checkboxes with all stylist names. When a user selects/unselects a stylist the corresponding column in the table should be showed/hidden. The data for populating the table will come from a json object. Also when an appointment lasts more 2 hours or more the cells that represent it should be joined.

I'm not a professional developer, so I can use some help. Is there a UI library that I can use? How do manipulate the table efficiently?

Thanks,
Anna

Comment: Do you have any code already that we can build off of? (i.e. JSON structure, HTML)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There plenty of plugin already available for altering tables but all require sum setting up to do and have there advantages to disadvantages.

A simple Google search for "Jquery table" return quite a lot but you mention to need json importing so there will be requited to convert.

The best choise would be Jtable, it will provide everything you need to start. 
http://www.jtable.org/

They have a great demo of real time actions: http://www.jtable.org/RealTime